How to remove a file from an application installed in windows (MSI created using InstallShield) using another installer
I have a main installer created using InstallShield (Basic MSI type). After release we deliver patches (InstallScript type) incase if found any critical bugs. This time when i delete a file from the main installer (from the install location in windows) through patch MSI, one of our compnents stopped working and the main MSI is trying to fix by itself. The deletion process in patch msi project is done bya simply delete command using install script.
Can someone suggest what is the right approach for this?
Steps followed

Installed the main installer MSI in a winows11 machine (Basic MSI type).
Installed the patch on top of that (install script MSI).
The patch msi has a delete command and it deleted a file from the install location of main MSI.
Then ran one of our components which was expecting that deleted file over there (The same file is available in a different place as well)

